# Convert KML to shapefile using GDAL/OGR2OGR to include all attributes from description field

Tags: gdal, convert, kml, ogr2ogr, html

I'm currently trying to develop a workflow for converting KML to shapefile using OGR2OGR command within GDAL.  The conversion seems to work fine for some KMLs that have basic information included within the Description.  However, when the Description contains fields populated with HTML tags, it doesn't recognize the content, and cannot parse the data into fields within the Shapefile.  I found a "KML Tools" plugin for QGIS that has a tool called "Expand HTML Description Field" that will do exactly what I need.  The problem is QGIS may not be approved to install on our network, however, GDAL is.  That said, I'm trying to use GDAL to build the solution.

Here's the basic command that works with very basic KMLs:

```
ogr2ogr Placemarks_Sample_Converted.shp Placemarks_Sample.KML
```

What I need to find is the proper syntax for reading the description field, and splitting the data out into fields based on the HTML tags ( and ) within it.

Here's snippet from the Description field:

```
    <tr>

    <td>PRODUCT</td>

    <td>7-day QPF</td>

    </tr>
```

I've seen a lot of KML/KMZ files structured this way, and I'm hoping someone has had luck writing some GDAL commands to do this conversion.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of "KML Tools" plugin? Maybe there is some reusable code.

Comment: I tried to review the log created after running the KML Description Field Expansion tool within the KML Tool Plugin, but it didn't expose the code.  Is there another way to see what's running behind the scenes?

Comment: The source code is here https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-kmltools-plugin and the name of the file htmlExpansionAlgorithm.py feels promising.

Comment: It looks like it uses Python scripts behind each tool. From what I can tell they're setup to run within a GUI and not from a stand alone script.  Bummer.  I was hoping to find something fairly straightforward where I could hard code the parameters into the script or command.  Yeah I'm sure there's a way to alter the Python to do so, but my level of experience with Python has been pretty basic (i.e. the ArcPy module within ArcGIS).